# how can i use a defined function in my database with entity framework core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to use entity framework core to get data from database instead of using sql request like in this exemple : 
`SELECT INT_To_STR(CODE), LIBELLE FROM TABLE2`
will be replaced by :

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseOracle(ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ccy>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Table2");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Code);
            entity.Property(e => e.Code).HasColumnName("CODE");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("LIBELLE");
        });
    }
```

the problem that i am facing is that i want to use the function 'INT_To_STR' 
Is there any solution? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think you should try to implement the INT_To_STR in c#. Even if that gives some initial hastle. Then get whatever is in the database 1-to-1, and use the c# method after.

Comment: thanks thomas but the objectif is not to reimplement ever function in c#, there a lot of functions that I will use and it will be a waste of time if i reimplement them all.

Comment: Take a look at [Scalar function mapping](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/).

Comment: Thanks @MarkG that was very helpful, I implemented this method
`[DbFunction(FunctionName = "INT_To_STR")]
        public static string INT_To_STR(int CODE)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`
but every time I get the Exeption declared in the method.

Comment: Assuming you're using EF Core 2.0 it should work, but it could be related to the provider you're using (see [limitations](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/tree/release/2.2/samples/OracleProvider#limitations-of-the-sample-oracle-provider)).  If using Oracle [provider](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html) you can provide [feedback](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/odp.net) on issue.

Comment: I am using EF Core 2.1, the problem now that it adds qoutes to the name of function like that : `SELECT "int_to_str"("c".CODE) AS "Code", "c".LIBELLE AS "Name"
FROM TABLE2 "c"`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on [query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types). With their help you can call user-defined functions in your database like this:

```
context.[QUERYTYPE].FromSql("SELECT [FUNCTIONNAME] ...")
```

Comment: thanks @Grimm, but if i wil use .FromSql( ), EF Core will not be efficient because it's simply uses sql request to do the work. I was thinking about using `.HasDefaultValueSql()` or `.HasValueGenerator()` but it seems not working.

Comment: EF Core (the database driver for EF Core to be exact) always uses SQL - so this approach can't be less efficient. It might even be more efficient as manually written queries tend to be more efficient than EF Core generated ones (depending on your SQL skills of course). What you might want to use are computed columns to have the results of INT_To_STR already (pre)calculated in your database. You can define them in your model builder via modelBuilder.Entity<ENTITYNAME>().Property(p => p.COMPUTEDCOLUMNNAME).HasComputedColumnSql("INT_To_STR(CODE)");

Comment: As you can see I already used the aproach of using SQL.
The new idea is to get rid of All that and replace it with EF Core without using .FromSql( )
`using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
            {....
                 while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0) && !reader.IsDBNull(1))
                    {
                        ccyList.Add(new Ccy(
                            reader.GetString(0),
                            reader.GetString(1)));
                    }
                }

            }`

Comment: Well, if you don't want to reimplement functions in C# and don't want to use .FromSql() then I only see computed columns as the way to go. Thus you can get the result of INT_To_STR transparently without reimplementing it in C# and without calling that function explicitly with .FromSql(). A nice benefit from that is that you can even define an index on that computed column if speed/efficiency is a concern for you (as I assume from your previous comment).